# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation), error appears even if I used the libraries before

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I'm getting these errors when trying to develop my first app. Note that the first one is just a warning.

> Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found

> Undefined symbols:
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is a simple app which should scan a barcode and render a message based on whether the scanned barcode was found in the database or not. The database is static.

Those are the main files of the program, can anyone tell me what is the problem? The problem is likely in the ViewController.

```
//  CameraView.swift

import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CameraViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ViewController

    @Binding var scannedResult: String?
    @Binding var showCameraView: Bool
    
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        let controller = ViewController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator as? any CameraViewControllerDelegate
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        // Update the view controller if needed
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
        var parent: CameraViewController

        init(_ parent: CameraViewController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
            // Handle barcode scanning and update the scannedResult
            if let barcodeData = metadataObjects.first as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject, let barcode = barcodeData.stringValue {
                parent.scannedResult = StaticDatabase.database[barcode] ?? "Good to Use"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
//  QadyatyApp.swift
//  Qadyaty
//
//  Created by Omar Nagy on 24.10.23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scannedResult: String?
    @State private var showCameraView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Image("Palestine")
                    .resizable()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                VStack {
                    Text("قاطع فأثر صغير خير من عجز ضعيف")
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()

                    Text("افحص باركود المنتج لتعرف إن كان في قائمة")
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .padding()

                    Text("المقاطعة")
                        .font(.system(size: 48))
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding()

                    Spacer()

                    Button(action: {
                        // Open the camera view when the button is tapped
                        showCameraView = true
                    }) {
                        Text("افحص")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                    }
                    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showCameraView) {
                                            CameraViewController(scannedResult: $scannedResult, showCameraView: $showCameraView)
                                        }

                    Text("DEVELOPED BY OMAR NAGY")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Main Screen")
        }
    }
}
```

```
//  ContentView.swift
//  Qadyaty
//
//  Created by Omar Nagy on 24.10.23.
//

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


struct StaticDatabase {
    static let database = [
        "123456789012": "Boycott",
        "9876543210": "Good to Use"
        // Add more barcode-message pairs as needed
    ]
}



protocol CameraViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func barcodeScanned(result: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate{
    
    weak var delegate: CameraViewControllerDelegate?
        
    let scanButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Scan", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    var video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupUI()
        setupCamera()
    }
    
    func setupUI() {
        view.addSubview(scanButton)
        
        scanButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        scanButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        scanButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        scanButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        scanButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scanButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func scanButtonTapped() {
        if session.isRunning {
            session.stopRunning()
            scanButton.setTitle("Scan", for: .normal)
        } else {
            session.startRunning()
            scanButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        }
    }
    
    func setupCamera() {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            session.addInput(input)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        session.addOutput(output)
        output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13]
        
        video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        video.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(video)
    }
    
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
            // Handle barcode scanning and communicate the result through the delegate
            if let barcodeData = metadataObjects.first as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject, let barcode = barcodeData.stringValue {
                let result = StaticDatabase.database[barcode] ?? "Good to Use"
                delegate?.barcodeScanned(result: result)
            }
        }
    
    func checkBarcode(_ barcode: String) {
        // Simulate a product database check
        let database = ["123456789012": "Boycott"]
        
        if let result = database[barcode] {
            showAlert(title: "Result", message: result)
        } else {
            showAlert(title: "Result", message: "Good to Use")
        }
    }
    
    func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```